# How to find and print pair key in a map c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, std-pair

Im trying to create a function that takes in two strings and finds the edit distance between both. Right now im working on set up a map that contains almost all the keys on the keyboard, along with a pair that gives that key's coordinate, EX: q = (1,0). Now im trying to figure out how to find a specific key in my map, and print its coordinates. My last line of code isn't getting me the pair, what's the correct syntax?

```
map<char, pair<int,int>> mapsetup(){
map<char, pair<int, int>> keyMap = {
        {'1',make_pair(0,0)},{'2',make_pair(0,1)},{'3',make_pair(0,2)},{'4',make_pair(0,3)},{'5',make_pair(0,4)},{'6',make_pair(0,5)},{'7',make_pair(0,6)},
        {'8',make_pair(0,7)},{'9',make_pair(0,8)},{'0',make_pair(0,9)},{'q',make_pair(1,0)},{'w',make_pair(1,1)},{'e',make_pair(1,2)},{'r',make_pair(1,3)},
        {'t',make_pair(1,4)},{'y',make_pair(1,5)},{'u',make_pair(1,6)},{'i',make_pair(1,7)},{'o',make_pair(1,8)},{'p',make_pair(1,9)},{'a',make_pair(2,0)},
        {'s',make_pair(2,1)},{'d',make_pair(2,2)},{'f',make_pair(2,3)},{'g',make_pair(2,4)},{'h',make_pair(2,5)},{'j',make_pair(2,6)},{'k',make_pair(2,7)},
        {'l',make_pair(2,8)},{';',make_pair(2,9)},{'z',make_pair(3,0)},{'x',make_pair(3,1)},{'c',make_pair(3,2)},{'v',make_pair(3,3)},{'b',make_pair(3,4)},
        {'n',make_pair(3,5)},{'m',make_pair(3,6)},{',',make_pair(3,7)},{'.',make_pair(3,8)},{'/',make_pair(3,9)}
    };
    return keyMap;
}

int main(){
map<char, pair<int,int>> mapt = mapsetup();
string target, typo;

cout << "Enter target string" << endl;
getline(cin, target);
cout << "Enter typo string" << endl;
getline(cin, typo);

cout << mapt.find('a')->second << endl;

}
```

Comment: What's your question? Does the code compile? Does it do the wrong thing?

Comment: cout << mapt.find('a')->second << endl; doesnt get my the pair from my map? how can i go about printing out the coordinates from a specific key

Comment: If you're getting a compiler error, you should add that to the question.

Answer (score 1):

On this line:

```
cout << mapt.find('a')->second << endl;
```

you are trying to print a `pair<int,int>`. But `operator<<` for `cout` doesn't know how to handle a pair.

Instead, you can do:

```
auto i = mapt.find('a'); 
cout << i->second.first << " " << i->second.second << endl;
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/E3nKaK).

Alternatively, you could overload the `operator<<` to do the right thing when given a pair:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const pair<int, int> &p) { 
    return out << p.first << " " << p.second; 
}
```

and now you can use your original syntax:

```
cout << mapt.find('a')->second << endl;
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dKEo6v).